# Where to find screenShots / Attachments in iTunes Connect Resolution Center?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunes-app

I'm a new developer and uploaded my first app on iTunes Connect. My app is got rejected and that wrote
 "**Your app or its metadata appears to contain misleading content. Specifically, your app creates a misleading association with another app in the Google Play Store, APP_NAME.
Please see attached screenshots for details.**"
But I'm not able to find any attachment in all iTunes Connect. At the end its written 
"**These attachments may display potentially objectionable content, such as nudity, pornography, and profanity.**"
My app is simple educational app...
Can somebody help me where I find these screenshots. As I mailed them twice, But got same copy-pasted reply.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This label appears even if there is no attachments.

**Some message with attachments:**
[image: Some message with attachments]

**Another message without attachments:**
[image: Another message without attachments]

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in iTunes connect resolution centre at bottom of the page.In my case it is here.[image]

Comment: could u please share screenshot... in my case its written "These attachments may display potentially objectionable content, such as nudity, pornography, and profanity." in Bold RED and no attachments are shown.

Comment: Actually they are sending screenshots but they stripped in-between.  Finally after 3-4 attempts Got 2 screenshots from them ( Though still 2 are stripped).

Answer (score 0):

Use below path with screenshots :- 
1. Select your application from **My Apps.** 
2. Select your application version so as a detail page you will get all information about the version. 
[image]

3. At the end of page below title **Additional Information** you will get **Resolution center.** 
   [image]

From above path you will get all information about your **App rejection.**

Comment: I'm able to find resolution centre..My question is "In reason they said see attachment for more info AND I'm not able to find that attachment". Where to find that attachment

Comment: have you open resolution center? when you open resolution center then your site path will be.... ios versions > resolution center.

Comment: Yes I opened..The image I posted in question is of Resolution Centre itself. Apple attached some screenshots in that ..I'm not able to find that

Comment: I am not sure about screen shot. But i think you have to update your application rating as per below link.
https://gist.github.com/acidjazz/6017f4ffe407df0381b64981800278e1

Comment: its a fairly simple Kids Educational App. Please see the attached image in question.